# Formatting textarea

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I am using Magento CE 1.9 and I have a custom tab on my product page called from an attribute. The attribute is a text area with comma delimited data. How would I go about formatting the data so it's more legible on the product page and not all bunched together? Is there a way to separate the comma delimited data on the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml` to your local template directory preserving the path `catalog/product/view/`.

Now around line 44 change

```
<td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
```

to

```
    <td class="data">
<?php 
    if ($_data['code'] == 'your_attribute_code'):
        $value = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);
        $value = explode(',', (string)$value);
        /**
         * Format $value some more if you want, for example:
         */
        $value = '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>',$value).'</li></ul>';
        echo $value;
    else:
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: It just returns the text "Array"

Comment: the comment part means that you should format the array of values however you like. I've updated with code to create a list

Comment: Got it, I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Using: $value = '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>',$value).'</li></ul>'; is there a way to display the data in alphabetical order descending?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php and use the flag SORT_STRING I think

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `catalog/product/attributes.phtml` file and remove the comma's from the attribute like this:

replace

```
echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])
```

with

```
if($_data['code'] == 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE') {

    $value = explode(',', $data['value']);
    arsort($value); //descending sort
    $value = '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>',$value).'</li></ul>';
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $value, $_data['code']);

    //do any formatting change in the above line.
} else {
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);
}
```

This will remove comma and replace it with space. Depends on how you want to format your data, you can put newline (`<br>`) or anything in the replace_with argument.

Comment: I don't use it in the view.phtml file, I call it from catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml for a custom tab on the product page.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Using: $value = '<ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>',$value).'</li></ul>'; is there a way to display the data in alphabetical order descending?

Comment: check updated answer